# Как вывести последние статьи из Рубрики блог на главную под виджетом контакта у меня на сайте

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Как вывести последние статьи из Рубрики блог на главную под виджетом контакта у меня на сайте.
Сейчас у меня на главной стоит виджет комментариев от ВК. Я хочу что бы сразу после него на этой же главной странице шли последние публикации вместо Раздела блог. Как это сделать? 
Страница у меня стоит статичная.
Cайт  - [zombitime.com](http://zombitime.com)

Answer (score 1):

1. Написать скрипт на `php`, который будет формировать структурированные данные последних публикаций из блога.
2. На статичной странице внедрить код `js`, который будет делать `ajax` запрос к скрипту `php`.
3. Выводить полученные данные на страницу в подготовленный блок с помощью того же `js`.